# Incomprehensible audit in Low Quality Posts

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

In the Low Quality Posts queue, I have failed this [review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7201677).

The short version of question and answer:

[Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462410/acoustic-fingerprint-opensource): I wan't some tool for doing something.
A: You can use the [Some magic tool](http://stackoverflow.com).

I have opened the question and flagged it as `off-topic`. After that I have pressed `Looks OK` because the answer is looks like it answers the question.

Am I wrong? Should I flag all answers for this question as `VLQ`?

Comment: I think you were expected to recommend deletion as link-only.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have opened the question and flagged it as off-topic"? If you opened it in a new tab, none of those actions are tracked by the review system - only what you do in the review queue is tracked. You needed to take action there, because it certainly doesn't "Look OK" based on your description.

Comment: @AlexK If we take a look only at the answer then it is a bad answer. If we consider the answer in the context of the question then it's a good answer to a bad question. So, I flagged the question instead. The answers is `Looks OK` in the context of the question.

Comment: @nempoBu4 without seeing the full answer, I can't say anything, but if it is as you say it is, then it STILL is not "Looks OK" - it is a link-only answer. Both the question and the answer is bad. Though I see your point about the question being bad, the answer is bad also, and is not "Looks OK" in any context.

Comment: Sometimes the review audits are sketchy. We just learn to live with it (see related links on right). But a single failed audit won't get a review ban. In the grand scheme of things failing one or two strange audits here and there doesn't generally affect much. It happens. Your review ban was due to multiple failed audits.

Comment: @AlexK Not all link-only answers considered to be so bad that they have to be removed. Especially if the answer is answers the question without using the link. In Low Quality Posts queue there are only three options: `Looks OK`, `Edit` and `Delete`. So, If the answer is bad, I cannot `Downvote` it during review. I've updated my question. So, if someone take a look at answer then someone can google for `Some magic tool` without using the link.

Comment: @JasonC I'm not asking about ban. I've removed the sentence about ban so it did not bother anyone anymore. I want to understand what is wrong in my actions.

Comment: @AlexK: Added quote of the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take a look at the answer (it contained a link):

> You guys should try this ACR provider: `http://syntec.tv`

That's clear-cut link-only, and probably even SPAM.
For corroboration, we cannot look at the user anymore, because that was destroyed.
We can take a look at the question though:

> #### Acoustic fingerprint opensource?
>
> Someone know any acoustic fingerprint API opensource or freeware? Preferable windows compatible. I only need the fingerprint part, not to connect to a remote DB to check audio metadata
>
> Thanks

It was asked March 17 2010, nearly five years ago.
That means the answer is a late answer and merits extra scrutiny: Spammers and astro-turfers (which are the slightly more intelligent variety) love to leave their litter on old questions, especially on bad recommendation-questions.

While close- and down-voting that question was certainly right, it does not obviate the need to moderate the answer too.

Comment: "While close- and down-voting that question was certainly right, it does not obviate the need to moderate the answer too."  My thoughts exactly.  No point in leaving a job half-done.

Answer (score 2):

That is not an answer. It is a link to a completely broken company website (a vague homepage, and all the other links are 404). It's a very bad attempt at spam - you should have flagged it.

Comment: ...and, as always, [There is no shame in using “Skip”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601)